# removeEventListener doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code to listen and remove the event. However, the event doesn't get removed:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    this.controlColumnWidth(event, startOffset, column)
})
window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.controlColumnWidth)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You are adding event `mousemove` and removing event `mouseup`. The events do not match

Comment: Also the function is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing two different events here, `mousemove` and `mouseup`.

Also you need to make sure you remove the same `(event) => { ... }` function instance that was originally registered:

```
const handler = event => {
  this.controlColumnWidth(event, startOffset, column);
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove', handler);
window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handler);

// You can also store the handler on `this` if you need to remove
// the event in a different function (such as in the destroyed hook)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man for the code. However, what I need to do is when mouseup event fires, mousemove should be removed. Anyway, this is possible?

Comment: @Sanjay just call the `removeEventListener` function inside the event handler function for the `mouseup` event.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Gotcha!